# How to cleanup useEffect callback?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

According to [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/de/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-3-main-to-renderer), one should use callbacks to communicate from main to renderer.

When using `useEffect`, how can one cleanup `window.api.test` using `return` function to prevent multiple instances of callback from being fired?

Looking for callback equivalent to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` model.

**preload.ts**

```
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from "electron"

export interface API {
  test: (callback: () => void) => void
}

const api: API = {
  test: (callback) => {
    ipcRenderer.on("test", (event) => {
      callback()
    })
  },
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", api)
```

**renderer.tsx**

```
…
useEffect(() => {
  window.api.test(() => {
    console.log("test fired")
  })
  return () => {
    // Cleanup window.api.test somehow…
  }
}, [])
…
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach when adding event handlers is to return a function that can be used to remove it.

Unfortunately `ipcRenderer.on()` doesn't do this () but you can create your own

```ts
type ListenerCallback = () => void;
type Remover = () => void;

export interface API {
  test: (listener: ListenerCallback) => Remover;
}

const api: API = {
  test: (callback) => {
    const listener = (event: Event) => {
      callback();
    };

    ipcRenderer.on("test", listener);
    return () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeListener("test", listener);
    };
  },
};
```

Now your effect hook can use the return value in its cleanup

```ts
useEffect(() => {
  return window.api.test(() => {
    console.log("test fired");
  });
}, []);
```

See [ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, listener)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererremovelistenerchannel-listener)

Comment: Had just stumbled upon https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/issues/43#issuecomment-772303787… thanks for helping out Phil!

Comment: Btw, if anyone is wondering, one can also use `off` vs `removeListener`.

Comment: @sunknudsen I can't see any documentation for `off()`. If it works, it might not in future

Comment: Good point… strange hey?